# UIDocumentMenuViewController showing on iPad gives "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ipad, uikit, autolayout, icloud, uialertcontroller

I'm having some problems showing a UIDocumentMenuViewController from a bar button item on the iPad. I do get the correct initial behavior and the menu is called from a barButtonItem as required, but before the delegate is called, I get some auto layout constraint messages which I'm not sure how to fix. This is how I call the UIDocumentMenu VC:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *documentMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[self fileUTIList] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentMenu.delegate = self;
documentMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
documentMenu.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.rightAddButton;
//documentMenu.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
//documentMenu.should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs
[self presentViewController: documentMenu animated:YES completion: ^{
    NSLog(@"DocumentPicker presented completion");
}];
```

I get the above completion handler is called correctly, and it looks fine on the iPad. But when I select an item for the menu, I immediately get a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" message:

```
2014-10-22 22:42:20.817 iPad[34421:474588] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c1d0f30 H:[UIView:0x7c1cbc20(304)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c1ddbf0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7c1cbc90.width == UIView:0x7c1ca670.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c14b310 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7c1ca670(142)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c151a80 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7c1cbc90.width >= UIView:0x7c1cbc20.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c1d0f30 H:[UIView:0x7c1cbc20(304)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-10-22 22:42:20.818 iPad[34421:474588] documentMenu: didPickDocumentPicker
```

Then the delegate for documentMenu is finally called, and the UIDocumentPickerViewController is presented, seemingly correctly:

```
- (void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker {
NSLog(@"documentMenu: didPickDocumentPicker");
documentPicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I'm afraid that this will have reprecussions and cause some weird display issues if I ship with this. Is there any way to identify what is exactly causing this behavior, since it seemingly comes from UIDocumentMenuViewController / UIAlertControllerView?

Comment: Not an answer, sadly, but for what it's worth Apple's Lister sample code (Swift variant) is consistently throwing a very similar warning for me on iOS 8.1 + Xcode 6.1

Comment: The objective-c version does as well. I'm guessing it's some internal issue. I pushed my update to the App Store and so far no one seems to be complaining about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

iPad have some special rules about ActionSheets and their cancel buttons, It usually depends on where you are displaying the ActionSheets from, so this is how you can resolve the crashing issue:

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeHTML as String ], in: .import)
importMenu.delegate = self
importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
importMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I've done exactly this and I am getting the crash in iOS 11.4.

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: I just fixed it by removing the `sourceView` line and instead specifying the `barButtonItem` like this: `documentProvider.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.buttonRestore`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this before presenting documentMenu:

```
[documentMenu.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: I filed a radar that probably will be duped: http://openradar.appspot.com/19385063

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem in my case (iOS 9.3.1 and iPhone 6/6s). I've duplicated @cescofry radar.

Comment: Some time back I added that line to fix a bug. In iOS 10 beta 4 and 5, however, it results in a more serious bug: the UIDocumentMenuViewController puts up a blank menu.

Comment: It Didn't help!

Comment: Things have gotten more complicated (helpful?) over the last couple years regarding constraints.  Please see Satnam Sync's answer.